# What is going on in this SQL: `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(),103)`

Tags: sql-server

I found this in some code that I was tasked with documenting:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

I ... don't get it. The first arg should be a `data_type`, not a string.
How is "LineFeed" a valid data_type?

It runs, and returns today's date (in SQL Server) so I must be missing something blindingly obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a valid data type, in addition to being a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

The parser is intelligent enough to know that in this context, CHAR is being used as a datatype.

Comment: bah! I knew I was being dense.

Comment: Or to the contrary, overthinking it.  I had to think twice about your reference to CHAR(10) being a "line feed"...then I realized what you were referring to, and had to give you credit for not being entirely wrong.   : )

Comment: @TabAlleman Can you please explain what he is referring to "line feed"? Could not understand it yet.

Comment: `SELECT CHAR(10)` is what he is talking about. @GGadde

Comment: @GGadde if you click the link on the word "function" in my answer, you'll see that CHAR() can be a function that returns the value of a character based on which index it is in the ASCII convention.   The 10th ASCII character is a Line Feed character.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman and Sami. I did not knew about this. Good to know. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function takes 3 arguments:

1. data type
2. expression
3. style

Your line `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)` meets this signature:

1. data type is `CHAR(10)`
2. expression is `GETDATE()`
3. style is `103`

The `GETDATE()` expression returns a `DATETIME` object which is converted to a `CHAR(10)` in the style specified by `103` (which is `dd/mm/yyyy` as per the site I linked to above).

Comment: All correct, but the relevant factor was that I'd mentally parsed CHAR(10) as the function invocation (returning the NewLine character) and failed to recognise it as a type definition.

Comment: Please don't include w3shools. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com